# Can't get data from JSON “undefined”

Tags: javascript, discord.js

"https://tripbot.tripsit.me/api/tripsit/getDrug?name=meth" Is the API, I tried to get the name in data, `{"err":null,"data":[{"name":"methamphetamine` **this's part of the json that I want**

I only want to get the name which is "methamphetamine" and embed it inside the Description, I tried using one of the methods to get the name from the JSON, but whenever I test it, it shows **undefined**.

Is there any way I can fix this and get the name from the JSON?

**Here's my code:**

```js
(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://tripbot.tripsit.me/api/tripsit/getDrug?name=meth`).then(r => r.text())
    const name = response.data.name
    const education = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#00000')
      .setTitle('Education │ education')
      .setDescription(`${name}`)
      .setFooter('Education ©, Test')
    message.channel.send(education);
})()
```

Comment: I am curious , isn't there any similar Q around ?

Comment: @AFarmanbar I'm pretty sure there might be a duplicate. But finding a dupe where `fetch` is requesting JSON encoded data, but `text` is used instead `json`. At least I wasn't able to find one up to now.

Comment: @AFarmanbar The closest thing I found right now is  [Node-Fetch API | What is text() stand for? (Promise issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666458/node-fetch-api-what-is-text-stand-for-promise-issue), but that's about the fetch module of node. I mean you can always vote for a dup even if it is already answered, there is nothing wrong about doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you use [`res.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json), not [`res.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text), as the response is JSON. Second, `data` is an array, so you'll need to grab its elements. There is a chance there is more than one element, so you could use the `.map()` method to iterate over the array and display everything you want:

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
const keyword = args[0];

(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://tripbot.tripsit.me/api/tripsit/getDrug?name=${keyword}`);
  const { data } = await response.json();
  const fields = data.map((field) => ({
    name: field.name,
    value: `Aliases: ${field.aliases.join(', ')}`,
  }));
  const education = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#00000')
    .setTitle('Education │ education')
    .addFields(fields)
    .setFooter('Education ©, Test');
  message.channel.send(education);
})();
```

[image]

If you only want to add the name(s):

```js
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`https://tripbot.tripsit.me/api/tripsit/getDrug?name=${keyword}`);
  const { data } = await response.json();
  const names = data.map((field) => field.name);
  const education = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#00000')
    .setTitle('Education │ education')
    .setDescription(names.join(', '))
    .setFooter('Education ©, Test');
  message.channel.send(education);
})();
```

Comment: [@Zsolt Meszaros] also what's the keyword for?

Comment: @Oince23 `keyword` is the phrase you're looking for ("meth" in your case). By making it a variable you can easily change it or use it for the user input. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: [@Zsolt Meszaros] Also, last question what If I only want the name? without the Aliases

Answer (score 2):

[`.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text) returns text (so the JSON encoded data that is not parsed).

What you are looking for is [`.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json), which parses the response end returns a JavaScript object with the data.

Further more, `response.data` is an array, so it has to be `response.data[0]` if you want the first element of it.

```js
(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://tripbot.tripsit.me/api/tripsit/getDrug?name=meth`).then(r => json())
    const name = response.data[0].name
    const education = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#00000')
      .setTitle('Education │ education')
      .setDescription(`${name}`)
      .setFooter('Education ©, Test')
    message.channel.send(education);
})()
```